# How to create Oracle Trigger to record current SQL

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am currently doing a homework assignment and am getting stuck at a point.
I want to create a trigger for auditing, and Yes I do know FGA, but that's not what was asked.
My trigger needs to record the current SQL for auditing. This is what I have now.
Imagine I have my table already created to store the inserting value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ALL_SQL_AUDIT
AFTER UPDATE ON SCOTT.EMP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ALL_SQL_AUDIT(TABLE_NAME, SQL_TEXT, SQL_TYPE, CHANGE_DATE, DB_USERNAME, OS_USERNAME)
SELECT 'SCOTT.EMP',
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL'),
    'UPDATE',
    SYSDATE,
    USER,
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER')
FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Problem is SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL') never return anything, so does anyone know how to get the current DML that triggered this event?

Comment: `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL')` is only populated when you are using FGA.  Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to get the `sql_id` from `v$session` but that won't work in general across versions.

Comment: So any suggestion on how to get the SQL that trigger the event? I actually read a thread on oracle discussion similar to what I am doing, and someone in there said having FGA on would not help me because FGA gets recorded after the trigger, so I would not be able to get current SQL through that either.

Comment: Here is that reference https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2135726

Comment: If you are using FGA, you would call `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL')` from within the event handler, not within a trigger defined on the table.  And, as I said, depending on the Oracle version, the `sql_id` from `v$session` may give you the triggering query but that doesn't work across all versions of Oracle.

Comment: I ended up using FGA in conjunction to my trigger. Like I said, I can't use FGA as the answer to my assignment, but I can use FGA as a helper. So I enable FGA to audit on insert, update, and delete. Then my trigger just insert the last row from audit_trail table with the same FGA policy_name. Seems to work well so far, not sure how it would be on concurrent process. I may have to take your approach on getting sql_id, but that is still is going to have issues.